# IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python

Пытаюсь выполнить INSERT в БД:

```
import psycopg2
import pprint
import sys

def main():

    caden = "host='localhost' dbname='my' user='postgres' password='postgrespass'"
    print(caden)

    obj = psycopg2.connect(caden)
    objCursor = obj.cursor()

    objCursor.execute("INSERT INTO _reference10( _idrref, _version, _marked, _predefinedid, _code, _description) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", ("\275\233\000\023waU\236\021\345\343\271\273\226\304\366",0 ,false ,"\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000" , "000000014", "Brazil14"))

    obj.commit()

    objCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM _reference10;")
    registr1=objCursor.fetchall()

    print(regist1)
    objCursor.close()
    obj.close()

if __name__ =='__main__':
     main()
```

Но возникает исключение:

> File "C:\Python\Projects\p.py", line 18
>       objCursor.execute("INSERT INTO _reference10( _idrref, _version, _marked, > _predefinedid, _code, _description) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
>   ("\275\233\000\023waU\236\021\345\343\271\273\226\304\366",0 ,false
>   ,"\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000" ,
>   "000000014", "Brazil14"))
>       ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent [Finished in 0.1s]

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Проверьте отступы на 18 строке, там наверняка перед objCursor.execute(..., лишний пробел(или таб) затесался.

Comment: У вас там вместо четырёх пробелов стоит таб.

Comment: Спасибо. Ошибка именно в этом

Answer (score 0):

Из комментариев:

---

На 18 строке вместо четырех пробелов табуляция - это и есть причина ошибки.